# PHPExcel does not rendering the design from exsiting template

Tags: file, yii, download, phpexcel

I'm using a template for my reports. I'm just editing the cells for the value needed.

I'm using PHPExcel and Yii framework.

```
public function generateSalesOrderReportExcel($id)
{
    set_time_limit(0);
    $templateFile =  Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/path/to/file.xlsx';
    $ext = strtolower(array_pop(explode(".", $templateFile)));
    $writerType = ($ext == "xls") ? 'Excel5' : 'Excel2007';

    Yii::import('ext.phpexcel.XPHPExcel');
    XPHPExcel::init();

    /* Cell caching to reduce memory usage. */
    $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;
    $cacheSettings = array('memoryCacheSize'=>'8MB');
    PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);

    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($writerType);
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(false);
    /* check if the the file is readable */
    if (!$objReader->canRead($templateFile))
        return false;
    /* load only the first sheet */
    $sheets = $objReader->listWorksheetNames($templateFile);
    $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly(array($sheets[0]));

    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($templateFile);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    // save the sales order report then download
    $fileName = 'SalesOrderReport-'.date('Ymd').'-'.time().'.xlsx';
    $filePath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/tmp/'.$fileName;
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $writerType);
    $objWriter->save($filePath);
    Yii::app()->getRequest()->sendFile($fileName, @file_get_contents($filePath));
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

My problem is the design from the existing template is not rendering when I saved it to a new file.

Comment: PHPExcel __should__ maintain the design (style, layout, etc) unless you'd setReadDataOnly to true... if it doesn't then something somewhere is overriding it, but this code doesn't give me any clues

Comment: Thanks mark, but if I setReadDataOnly to false then the browser says that No Data Received. I'm using google chrome. I'm still checking for the bugs.

Comment: I don't use Yii, but would it be possible to send me a copy of the template via the codeplex site so I can at least eliminate any direct PHPExcel issues with it

Comment: Hi mark, it's working now. I just used the Excel5 instead of Excel2007. Thanks for the help.